# Left join returning additional data which I want to exclude

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables like below :

```
Employee: 

EmployeeId
EmployeeName
DeptId

Transactions:

TRID   
EmployeeId
Status(Pending,Done,InProgress,Rejected)
```

Now I want to get all employees from the `EmployeeTable for DeptId = 100`. I want to calculate `Pending` status for those employees whose transactions are `pending`.

So if employee records are found in Transactions table then just want to return a column saying whether employee has any pending transactions or not)

**Query:**

```
SELECT
        e.*,
        CASE WHEN (t.EmployeeId is not null and t.Status!= 'Done')
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) 
            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
        End as IsPendingTransaction,
    FROM 
        Employee e
        left join Transactions t on e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
    where e.DeptId = 100
```

Now the problem is there are employees who have multiple transactions in transactions table but for those employees, I just wants to consider their latest transaction and
calculate IsPendingTransaction status based on that. Basically `order by Descending on TRID` while calculating IsPendingTransaction status for Employees from transaction table.
If employees dont have any transaction then IsPendingTransaction would be "False".

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support single quotes for string delimiters, so your code is suspicious.

Comment: You might be in for a rude awakening someday when someone back-dates a transaction or corrects an old transaction in a manner you don't consider. Be careful how you define "latest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT e.*,
       (CASE WHEN (t.EmployeeId is not null and t.Status <> 'Done')
             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) 
             ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
        End) as IsPendingTransaction
FROM Employee e OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t.*
      FROM Transactions t 
      WHERE e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
      ORDER BY t.trID DESC
     ) t
WHERE e.DeptId = 100;
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Do we need this condition "t.EmployeeId is not null" in IsPendingTransaction?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow . . . No.  First `NULL` values would not match.  Second, I would be surprised if it ever were `NULL` in the `Transactions` table.

Comment: Actually, It might be possible that not all employees in the Employee table will have transactions and since I was using left join, that's why I added a null checking condition. With your version, what would be the correct logic to calculate IsPendingTransaction?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow . . . The `NULL` check in the `CASE` is still there.

Comment: Ok. I will include the null check in my final query too. Thank you so much for quick help and nice outer apply logic. Helped me learn something new :)